# If a derived class' "reference" goes out of scope but the base class reference stays, does the derived object ever change?

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class

(In C# 5.0) It's a pretty simple yes/no question which I can't seem to find an explicit answer for which probably means I'm looking in the wrong place or using the wrong terms in searching for the answer.

If I create a derived class object, then I cast it to a base class and the original reference goes out of scope, does the reference held in the base class casting preserve the entire derived class object?  I.E. can I later recast it as the derived class with the original object always still intact?

Comment: if you have a reference via the base class, how would it be able to go out of scope? it still references the same object, it's not recreated.

Comment: (Up)Casting has nothing to do with this. It just makes the interpretation of type as base type; but still the instance is derived type. Even if you type it as `System.Object` it doesn't makes any difference. You can always (down)cast to derived type and it will be intact.

Comment: There is only 1 object, base and derived cannot be collected separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 6.1.6 (implicit reference conversions):

> Reference conversions, implicit or explicit, never change the referential identity of the object being converted. In other words, while a reference conversion may change the type of the reference, **it never changes the type or value of the object being referred to.**

(My emphasis)

---

Your question seems to be concerned that there may be something akin to [Object Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) happening - but that's not something that can happen in C#.

Comment: Thank you for that link - I will bookmark it.  One of the problems of not having taken any classes on programming is you miss out on being directed to some great resources.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse - I've also added a link to the wikipedia page on object slicing - since it sounds like that's what you were concerned might happen - but it doesn't in C#.

Comment: I haven't had any "object slicing" (thanks for the vocab term, this is what I was concerned about) - but I didn't want to get too far into what I'm working on assuming it doesn't happen and the fact that the downcasts were still working wasn't because the GC hasn't picked up the "sliced" part of the class...  It wasn't a problem I have had, but once I wondered might occur - IE, I was worried the re-downcast might fail if you wait too long and the GC has cut your object up.

Answer (score 1):

YES of course. If you cast to another type, you change only the view to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference to the same object. The compile-time type of the expression which has a value of that reference is irrelevant. It's important to understand that there really is only *one* object - it's not like there's a base class object and then an associated derived class object.

That's why you can downcast as well:

```
string x = "hello";
object y = x;
string z = (string) y;
```

All three variables have the same value - they're all references to the same object. No information is lost. The reference itself is just "a way of getting to an object" - the *variable* determines which references are valid, and informs the compiler about which members can be accessed via that variable, but it doesn't change the value itself.

Comment: I know the OP asked about references -- what about value types? Anything like slicing in C#?

Comment: I hadn't even thought about derived structs - are those possible?

Comment: "Structs can implement an interface but they cannot inherit from another struct." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) Hence no slicing.

Comment: @Default: When I say "reference" I mean reference, and when I say "variable" I mean variable. If I meant something else, I'd say so :) (That said, I've edited the second sentence for clarity.) For example, the name `x` refers to a variable of type `string` in my example. The value of that variable is a reference to a string object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES. A reference has an associated type but the type of the reference never influences the type of the instance the reference points to.

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

// Here we create an instance of B and assign it to a reference of
// type A (B is a subclass of A so this is correct). This doesn't
// change the type of B.
A a = new B();
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType()) // => prints B

// You can always assign to Object (doesn't change the type of the instance.
object o = a;
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType()) // => prints B

// And you can cast a reference to a different type, as long as they
// are compatible.
B b = (B)a;
Console.WriteLine(b.GetType()) // => prints B
```

Comment: Your answer is great, and I was going to accept it, but then someone gave the explicit reference to this in the C# documentation and I chose that answer as it's probably better for people who run across it to hear it directly from the devs.